# change UITableViewCell background color when selected

Tags: iphone

i have a UItableview and i want to change the cell background when it is seleceted and keep it like that so i tried to use 
                [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
but that made other cells get colored at same time and i dont know why
i also tried to use 
  [cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
but when i select another cell the background go back to white color
so any ideas for solving that problem??

Answer (score 3):

> `UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.selectedBackgroundView.frame];
>
>   [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
>
>   [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:backgroundView];
>
>   [backgroundView release];`

Comment: the problem is that when i select another cell the previous cell go back to white again and i dont wanna that

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to achieve multiselection? If so, AFAIK you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

since 3.0, set it in the willDisplayCell method:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITableViewCell by yourself class, i.e. MyTableViewCell and reimplement the selected function.

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.selectedBackgroundView.frame];
    [backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    [self setSelectedBackgroundView:backgroundView];
}
```